# How to solve this $2\times2$ linear system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

At the moment, I am a little bit confused. Here is the linear system I am trying to solve

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc|c}
    5 &  -1& 12 \\
    -1 & 2& 12 
   \end{array} \right)$$

I tried to solve it by multiplying the rows with several numbers but it does not show up a possible solution. Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use ***elementary row operations***.

It's very much like solving a system of two equations in two unknowns:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
5x - \,\;y &= 12\\
\\
-x + 2y &= 12\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
But instead, we use the *augmented coefficient matrix (remove the variables).

$$
 \left( \begin{array}{cc|c}
    5 &  -1& 12 \\
    -1 & 2& 12 
    \end{array} \right)
$$
First multiply the second row by 5, and then add row 1 to row 2:

$$
 \left( \begin{array}{cc|c}
    5 &  -1& 12 \\
    -1 & 2& 12 
    \end{array} \right) =
 \left( \begin{array}{cc|c}
    5 &  -1& 12 \\
    -5 & 10& 60 
    \end{array} \right)=
 \left( \begin{array}{cc|c}
    5 &  -1& 12 \\
    0 & 9& 72 
    \end{array} \right)
$$

Can you take it from here?

We want to end with something like

$$
 \left( \begin{array}{cc|c}
    a &  0& x \\
    0 &  b& y 
    \end{array} \right)
$$

That is, we end with $x = a, y = b$.

Comment: ok. Thx for your hint. However, I do not get it;( Which row would you multiply with which value?

Comment: lol;P Ok got it! THX!!!!

Comment: See the expanded answer above for the first reduction...

Comment: It is somewhat easier to first multiply the top row by 2 and add it to the second row. Then one does not have to care about fractions

Comment: Or multiply the second row by 5, then add the first row to the second row.